# Not able to access Google One Tap UI view's ID for automation in espresso Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, user-interface, android-espresso, google-identity

We have implemented Google One Tap for Android now as a functional test requirement we want to execute with espresso but google One tap UI view id's are not accessible.is there any way to access them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking components that are not in your app, you cannot use Espresso. But you can use [Ui Automator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/other-components/ui-automator) to do that.